# Configure JavaScript indentation to indent keys object literals

Tags: indentation, filetype-javascript

I'm using vim version 8.0 on OS X (installed through Homebrew) and it keeps indenting object literals wrong. The first key and only the first key is flush with the previous line. All subsequent keys are indented four spaces.

```
var object = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
};
```

as

```
var object = {
key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
};
```

The javascript indentation file is here.

```
/usr/local/share/vim/vim80/indent/javascript.vim
```

It is pretty clearly the pangloss/vim-javascript plugin.

```
cat /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/indent/javascript.vim  | head -n 5
" Vim indent file
" Language: Javascript
" Maintainer: Chris Paul ( https://github.com/bounceme )
" URL: https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript
" Last Change: August 25, 2016
```

STR:

```
% touch awesome.js
% vim -u NONE awesome.js

:set filetype=javascript
```

type out javascript example

[image]

```
gg=G
```

voilà incorrectly indented code.

[image]

If there isn't some hidden configuration setting that's causing the bundled indenter for javascript to act up, is there a way to completely shadow `<...>/indent/javascript.vim` and `<...>/syntax/javascript.vim` so I can start writing a replacement?

Comment: You will need to use `:filetype indent on` before `:set ft=javascript` to enable loading the indentation file. So your minimal test is a bit too minimal here :-) If I do this, it works as expected for me. Try adding `:filetype plugin indent on` to your vimrc. Does that fix it?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker my real vimrc already has `filetype plugin indent on` in it, but I will update the test and post new and better screenshots if anything changed.

Comment: Uh oh... Looks like it's back to the drawing board for figuring out what's up with my full vimrc. If I follow your suggestion I get the right indentation behavior.

Comment: [Try this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51). It's probably just some setting or plugin.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I figured it out. I had `set nomagic` and it looks like it was interfering with the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2016-12-16, the javascript.vim indenter will break if you `set nomagic`.

The current workaround is to *not* use `set nomagic`.

Comment: Note that you can expect lots of stuff to break when you change the `magic` setting. This is documented in [`:help 'magic'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27magic%27) :-) *"WARNING: Switching this option off most likely breaks plugins!  That is because many patterns assume it's on and will fail when it's off."*

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I thought there was some way to write regular expressions with an explicit magic level to prevent exactly this kind of thing from happening.

Comment: Yes, you can with `\m`. But almost no one does that.